# ExpressJS & AJAX - Session Returns Undefined

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, session

### **Structure**

I have an API hosted on a secure server with HTTPS.

as such: `https://example.com`

Also, I have a frontend `index.html` located on my Desktop.

---

### **Goal**

I would like to send an ajax post request to the api and have the api save a value in the session and retrieve it. Like so:

1. Index.html makes POST ajax request to API
2. API saves a value in session
3. Index.html makes POST ajax request to API
4. API prints out the value in session

---

### API Code

First I allowed connections from all origins by using `cors()`.
And I have set up my `session()` as so.

```
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: true,
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
        credentials: true,
    })
);
app.options(
    '*',
    cors({
        origin: true,
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
        credentials: true,
    })
);

app.use(session({
    secret: "wefwefwe",
    cookie: {
        sameSite: "none",
        secure: false,
        maxAge: 360000000
    },
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
```

And then there's these 2 routes which will be called by the `index.html`

```
app.post('/createSession', async (req, res) => {
    req.session['test'] = "HIIIII";
    res.send("200");
})
app.post('/getSession', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session['test']);
    res.send("200");
})
```

---

### AJAX Code

There are 2 ajax calls, one is to create the session and the other is to retrieve the session.

```
$.ajax({
        url: `https://example.com/createSession`, 
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });

$.ajax({
        url: `https://example.com/getSession`, 
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

---

### Problem

Upon POST to `/createSession`, I received this issue
[image]

However, when I changed secure to true - `secure: true`, The `/createSession` request doesn't even contain a `set-cookie` header.

Thus, when I POST to `/getSession`, it shows as `undefined`.

Could someone help me out with this please? For some reason I seem to get stuck with sessions on almost every project I embark on. :/